# Batch script for removing double quotes from a text file

Tags: batch-file

I receive a text file from an external source and it contains instances of two double quotes in a row that needs to be removed via a batch script.

ex: "Double quote"" example line."

When the script is completed it should read: "Double quote example line."

I tried the script below that does work, however it has an unintended consequence that I cannot figure out. Anytime a line contains an exclamation point and a colon, it deletes everything between them.

ex: "Hello! This line ran at 13:49."

This script turns this line into: "Hello49.".

Does anyone have an suggestions on fixing the unintended consequence or a better solution for removing any instance of two double quotes in a row?

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

(   for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (DateFile.txt) do (
        set "line=%%f"
        set "line=!line:""=!"
        echo(!line!
    )
) > NewDataFile.txt

endlocal
echo on
```

Comment: The problem is the `!` in the string and having delayed expansion enabled during assigning it (in `set "line=%%f"`)…

Answer (score 0):

You need to toggle your delayed expansion only where necessary.

Example:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
(   For /F UseBackQ^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ("DateFile.txt") Do (
        Set "line=%%G"
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        Echo(!line:""=!
        EndLocal
    )
) 1> "NewDataFile.txt"
```